# android TelephonyManagerのgetServiceStateがnullしか取れない

Tags: android

Android12で、TelephonyManager#getServiceStateを試しているのですが
取得結果がnullになってしまいます。

・AndroidManifest.xmlに以下の定義済み
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
・TestSevice.java

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {               
            ServiceState service = manager .getServiceState();※ここで戻り値がnullになる
            int state = service.getState();
        } 
    }
```

以下を見ると、TelephonyManager#getServiceState()で現在のサービス状態が取得できるようなのですが、
使用方法が異なりますでしょうか？
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getServiceState()